# Styled Components - Hover applied on child only not when hover on parent

Tags: css, styled-components

By using styled components

```
const element1 = style.div`
 background-color: red
 height: 200px
`

const element2= style.img`
  filter: blur 2px
`

<element1>
  <element2 />
</element1>
```

when `<element2>` is not nested i want the blur to be kept but when nested and on hover inside `<element1>` i want the blur to go. But ... i dont want the blur to disappear when i'm hovering over the parent(`<element1>`). Also if I have something like this:

```
<element1>
 <span>
   <element2>
 </span>
</element1>
```

I want the `<element2>` to keep the blur when hover, since is not directly below `<element1>`.

Is there a way by only using css to achieve that? i've spent a lot of time on this and i cant figure this out.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use the NOT pseudo class.

Comment: i've tried. couldnt find a workable solution. i was able to change when hover only over the element2, but when element2 was not nested was also changing. and couldnt work that out and i admit im not very experienced with css

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using styled components I'm going to structure my answer using that. Anyways, your elements should be:

```
const Element2 = styled.img`
  filter: blur(2px);
`;


const Element1 = styled.div`
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;

  &:hover > ${Element2} {
    filter: none;
  }
`;

const Element3 = styled.span`
  ${Element1} ${Element2} {
    filter: none;
  }
`;
```

While this is not a generalized way to do it, it's still a practical approach.

Here is the working example on code sandbox:

[image: Edit affectionate-kirch-7l4hc8]

Comment: your approach was my first solution, the thing is, once you hover over element1 the blur disappears. and the requirement is only changing when hover exactly the element2 and in my case i cant style a third component, like the additional span you did